# How to put animating placeholder image while downloading url image in swift 4 or Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, kingfisher

I did try with Cocapods "Kingfisher" but cannot figure out how to set an animating placeholder image while the image is being downloaded.
here is the Below code I tried with kingfisher Pod
[image: image Loader]

```
    func configureCell(category:Category){
        if let url = URL(string: category.imgUrl){
            let placeholder = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
            let options : KingfisherOptionsInfo = [KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.transition(.fade(0.1))]
            categoryImg.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            categoryImg.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: placeholder, options: options)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not an image but a UIView. The best option would be to use [SkeletonView](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView).

SkeletonView has been conceived to address this need, an elegant way to show users that something is happening and also prepare them to which contents he is waiting.

Answer (score 1):

This animation is called `Shimmer effect` . You can use this link for your help
[facebook/Shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer).